# Ember.js ViewState not appending View

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following ViewState definition:

```
App.LoggedIn = Ember.ViewState.create({
  view:  App.TopbarView.extend({
    elementId: 'topbar'
  }),
```

Is there anyway I can specify that I want this view appended to the element with topbar id?

The only I can find is to set the create the view in the enter handler.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you will be using that ViewState in a StateManager, correct?

If so, set the rootElement of the stateManager to topbar, and when this state is entered, this view will be appended to that element.

For example:

```
App.loggedIn = Ember.ViewState.create({
    view: App.TopbarView
});

App.stateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({
    rootElement: 'topbar',
    loggedIn: App.loggedIn
});
```

If you are unable to go that route, you can modify the enter function of the view state to find the topbar element and append the view to it.  Make sense?

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass an instance of View not a class for 'view' property. Try this

```
App.LoggedIn = Ember.ViewState.create({
  view:  App.TopbarView.create({
  elementId: 'topbar'
})
```

Comment: That is not correct: if the `view` is a class, it is instantiated for you, see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/5982731a69f6c5a853ac50269e1210616483c6e8/packages/ember-viewstates/lib/view_state.js#L254-257 . Also the question is how to *append* the view to a given element ...